# Why am i getting a runtime error while submitting this code online?(jdk 1.7)

Tags: java

This is the code (used IntelliJ idea jdk 1.8)
It worked well for me but shows a runtime error whenever I submit it in an online portal (jdk 1.7). What changes should I make?
I have no idea what is causing the error.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int n,k;
        int i=0;
        int sum=0;
        do {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String s = reader.readLine();
            n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            String s1 = reader.readLine();
            k = Integer.parseInt(s1);
            reader.close();



        }while ( n<0 || k>java.lang.Math.pow(10,9) || n<k );

        for (i=0 ; i<=k ; i=i+2){
            sum+=  fact(n)/(fact(i)*fact(n-i));
        }
        System.out.print(sum);

    }
    public static int fact(int n) {
        int j=1;
        while(n!=0){
            j=j*n;
            n--;
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```

I prefer not to use Scanner

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with JDK 1.7 and see if its actually a Java problem or the portal's problem?

Comment: Its possible that the online thing doesn't like default package. Put it in a package.

Comment: The portal doesn't show what the error is, it only displays "Runtime error".

Comment: What are your input values? It should be int , I tried with the String "test" and getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is pretty clear that the problem arises from `Main.main()` passing `null` to `Integer.parseInt()`.  It reports the `parseInt()` invocation appearing on line 18 of `Main.java`; that doesn't line up perfectly with your source as you presented it, but it's about right for this line:

```
            n = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

The string `s` at that point was just obtained via your `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method -- this indicates that there are no more data available from the underlying stream (ultimately, `System.in`).

That might be a bit surprising if it happened on the first iteration of your loop, but you ***close*** the `BufferedReader` yourself at the end of that iteration, and that closes all the wrapped `Reader`s and `InputStream`s as well.  On the second iteration, `System.in` is closed, and you are unable to read anything from it.  You should instead initialize your `BufferedReader` outside the loop, and wait to close it until after you exit the loop:

```
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        do {
             // do something with 'reader'
        } while ( /* some condition */ );

        reader.close();
```

Even if you were not closing the underlying stream, you certainly are buffering input from it, and then potentially tossing some of that buffered input along with the `BufferedReader`.  That in itself could cause your program to observe end-of-file earlier than it expected.  That might happen, for example, if you moved the `close()` outside the loop, but still created and read from a new `BufferedReader` on each iteration of the loop.

Moreover, it is wise to check upon each read whether a line was read successfully, and to handle the case where none was (indicated by `null` being returned).  For a submission to an online solution checker, however, it might be reasonable to assume that the input will conform to your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Often when using Online IDEs / compilers, you need to type the input **before** you run your program. The online tools may not prompt you for input, which can lead to your variables being set to null. A null variable will cause the error you are seeing.

How exactly to fix this depends on which online tool you are using. For example, if you are using Ideone, type your input into the "enter input (stdin)" or the "input" textboxes before running your program. For your program, since you are using readLine(), put the input on separate lines, as seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alkbT.png).

I copy and pasted your code into Ideone. If I didn't enter anything into the input textbox, I got the same error you saw. But if I entered the input before running the program, your code ran without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the string returned from readline() is number and not null.